# Directing traffic from USB(3.0) port to Ethernet output

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking, usb, ethernet

I am using an ASUS Tinker Board Single Board Computer(SBC) and am trying to direct all traffic into the USB(3.0) port and output it to the next device over the SBC's Ethernet connection as a UDP packet. The input data into the USB port is coming from an audio-to-USB adapter, as PCM samples. I have written the below code however this only works if the USB port on the SBC has a network address (which it does not).

```
import socket

UDP_IP_RX = "local_host"
UDP_PORT_RX = 5005
UDP_IP_TX = "local_host"
UDP_PORT_TX = 5006

sock_RX = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_TX = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_RX.bind((UDP_IP_RX, UDP_PORT_RX))

while True:
    MESSAGE, addr = sock_RX.recvfrom(2062)
    sock_TX.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP_TX, UDP_PORT_TX))
```

I understand that the USB port can't have a network address, however I have searched and can't find how I can direct traffic into the USB to somewhere else. The example code I know does not work but wanted to give insight as to what I am trying to do. Is there any way that I can direct the PCM samples from the USB port (input to SBC) to the Ethernet connection (output from SBC)?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think python has anything in the standard library for communicating via usb. There is a C library: [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/), and a Python wrapper for this library: [libusb1](https://github.com/vpelletier/python-libusb1), that might be worth looking into.

Comment: The Python wrapper libusb1 is great but it doesn't allow for directing input. It's great to get info such as which USB ports are in use and what the USB ports COM port is. Thanks anyways though @alxwrd.